# Sorting find command by filename

Tags: linux, find, alphabetical

I am looking to sort the output of a find command alphabetically by only the filename, not the whole path.

Say I have a bunch of text files:

```
./d/meanwhile/in/b.txt
./meanwhile/c.txt
./z/path/with/more/a.txt
./d/mored/dddd/d.txt
```

I am looking for the output:

```
./z/path/with/more/a.txt
./d/meanwhile/in/b.txt
./meanwhile/c.txt
./d/mored/dddd/d.txt
```

I have tried:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | sort -t
find . -name '*.txt' -exec ls -ltu {} \; | sort -n
find . -name '*.txt' | sort -n
```

...among other permutations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The straightforward way would be to print each file (record) in two columns -- filename and path -- separated by some character sure to never appear in the filename (`-printf '%f\t%p\n'`), then sort the output on first column only (`sort -k1`), and then strip the first column (`cut -d$'\t' -f2`):

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\t%p\n' | sort -k1 | cut -d$'\t' -f2
```

Just note that here we use the `\t` (tab) and `\n` (newline) for field and record separators, assuming those will not appear as a part of any filename.